# When is the exponential of a map proper?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then if $f: A \to B$ is a map between *discrete* spaces, the induced map $f^\ast: X^B \to X^A$ is proper.

**Question:** Are there other classes of map $f: A \to B$ such that $f^\ast: X^B \to X^A$ is proper for every compact Hausdorff space $X$?

**Notes:**

- Part of what I find puzzling about the state of affairs is that when $A$ and $B$ are discrete, we *don't* need to assume that $f$ itself is proper in order to conclude that $f^\ast$ is proper.
- Of course, in order for the question to make sense, we should probably assume that $A$ and $B$ are [exponentiable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces) (locally compact Hausdorff is fine). For all I know, though, it may be the case that there are spaces $A$ which are not exponentiable in general, but for which $X^A$ exists for every compact Hausdorff space; the question would make sense for $A,B$ of this form as well.
- I'm not certain that restricting $X$ to be compact Hausdorff is the most interesting thing to do, so I'd be interested in this question for other $X$'s as well.

Comment: A small note: if $X^A$ exists for $X$ the Sierpinski space, then $A$ is exponentiable. This doesn't yet address the situation with $X^A$ existing for all compact Hausdorff $X$, but for what interest it has I'm mentioning it.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"?

Comment: @WlodAA I mean that the preimage of every compact set is compact.

Comment: My stab in the dark is that local homeomorphisms are approximately what you want.

Comment: I find Claim 0 overly strong. Take $X=G$ a compact Lie group, and take $A\to B$ to be $\{0\}\to [0,1]$. Then your map is $ev_0$, evaluation at 0 of the free path space, with fibre the based path space of $G$, which is not compact (I guess this works for $X$ any compact manifold etc), hence $ev_0$ is not proper.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Point well taken. I'm having trouble verifying for myself that the path space is not compact, but we can take $A \to B$ to be $\emptyset \to S^1$ with $X = S^1$ and then the resulting map is $(S^1)^{S^1} \to \ast$, and $(S^1)^{S^1}$ is noncompact because it has infinitely many path components.

Comment: I'd be uneasy about working with the empty space in this case, in case that was "too simple to be simple", but your argument is fine taking $A=pt$ as well.

Comment: Thank you for the definition of "proper". When $\,B\,$ is discrete then $\,f\,$ is arbitrary. Doesn't it cover all possibilities -- what would be the "*other*"?

Comment: @WlodAA I know that if $f: A \to B$ is an arbitrary map where $A$ and $B$ are both discrete, then $f^\ast : X^B \to X^A$ is proper for all compact Hausdorff $X$. If it's unnecessary to assume $A$ is discrete, I'd love to hear about that! I'm ultimately interested in cases where neither $A$ nor $B$ is discrete.

Comment: I made a funny error writing about $B$ rather than $A$.

Comment: @WlodAA If it's only  necessary to assume that $A$ is discrete and not $B$, I'd love to hear about that too.